# Why is my ad affecting my gradient?

Tags: html, css, gradient, ads, adsense

I'm using a background-gradient which was working excellently across the entire page until I placed an ad on top. Shortly after I placed an ad from Google AdSense, the gradient abruptly stopped about 3/4 down the page.

Sure enough, when I remove the ad the gradient worked normally again.

Any idea why this is happening / what I can do to fix the issue?

**edit
if it helps, I placed the add code in the body of my code, and adjusted its position through the html

Thanks in advance for any help!

Best

Comment: Can you please provide an example of some sort? A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be helpful.

Comment: I added a picture - hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, an image isn't that helpful in this case. Some relevant coding would be, though... You *could* try `html,body{height:100%;}`.. that might work.

Comment: Josh Crozier - you mad genius, the simplest solution is often the best - it worked!